# Which account type to use for claimable expense I pay upfront for my employer?

Tags: accounting, gnucash

I am using GNUCash for personal finance. Sometimes I pay expenses upfront for my employer with cash or credit card. My employer will pay me back later with cash or cheque. I am thinking of using Account Receivable to keep track of these transactions. Is that the right account type to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used Quicken, so this may or may not be helpful.

I have a Cash account that I call "Temporary Assets and Liabilities" where I track money that I am owed (or that I owe in some cases).  So if I pay for something that is really not my expense, it is transferred to this account ("transferred" in Quicken terms).  The payment is then not treated as an expense and the reimbursement is not treated as income--the two transactions just balance out.